# Oracle package specs and body

Tags: oracle, plsql

So I know that if you define something in the package specification, that it must be implemented in the body.  Is it possible to define a method in the body, but not the spec?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, a procedure or function can be defined in a package body but not in a package specification.  Objects in the specification are public, objects only in the body are private to that package.

**Creating the package specification and body**

```
create or replace package test_package is
    procedure public_procedure;
end;
/

create or replace package body test_package is
    procedure private_procedure is
    begin
        null;
    end;

    procedure public_procedure is
    begin
        private_procedure;
    end;
end;
/
```

**How to call the package**

```
--WORKS:
begin
    test_package.public_procedure;
end;
/

--FAILS WITH THIS ERROR:
--  ORA-06550: line 2, column 15:
--  PLS-00302: component 'PRIVATE_PROCEDURE' must be declared
--  ORA-06550: line 2, column 2:
begin
    test_package.private_procedure;
end;
/
```

**Why would you need to do this?**

In a language like Java this question would probably be closed for being too obvious.  But this is an understandable question in PL/SQL, since most PL/SQL programmers make everything public.  Looking at an average PL/SQL program it's reasonable to say to yourself: "there must be a good reason for this."

There isn't.

Private should be the default.  Only make something public if you *need* to share it with other objects and programmers.  Or if you need to have something persist during a session.

Use private procedures and functions to hide as many details as possible.  This makes packages simpler.  It also gives other programs and programmers fewer ways to abuse your package.

Comment: Thank you for detailing so much.  Your answer went above and beyond!